# Maximum Length of String in Delphi property Lines of TMemo

Tags: delphi, tmemo

I've been searching the reason why the maximum length of String in a TMemo.Lines is 1024, but not found yet.

I have a text file which contains delimited / csv data which length is around 2000 characters.
I use a memo to preview it before I process the file.

memo.Lines.LoadFromFile(textFile);

I have set the WordWrap to FALSE, and scrollBar to ssHorizontal. So any record will not be wrapped to the next line.

But when I iterate the memo.Lines, I found that the maximum String hold in each index is 1KB or 1024 characters. The rest is truncated to the next line.

But if I use TStringList to load the file, the row is not truncated to the next index when it reaches more than 1024 characters. This is not happen when I use TRichEdit.

1. Anyone can explain this phenomena?
2. Is it the default behavior of TMemo?

I use D2006 to try this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WishKnew try this links

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=14035

http://www.borlandtalk.com/line-length-in-tmemo-vt67596.html

http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.vcl.components.using/browse_thread/thread/318fe3240d2860ba

As the great Peter Below says :

> ...This has nothing to do with the
>   appearend line  length limit. This
>   limit is really just visual, caused by
>   the way the control renders its text.

Bye.

Comment: -1 for just posting links with no explanation or summary.

Comment: The actual answer can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74225

Answer (score 1):

There's a TeamB answer on this thread:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=14035

I'm surprised that TStringList didn't work for you. I'm not quite sure what you mean by

> the row is not truncated to the next
>   index when it reaches more than 1024
>   characters.

I'm assuming the lines are delimited by newlines or CRLFs. Why would it matter if a CSV line exceeded 1024 characters? Please post more details.

Comment: I use TMemo to preview the file before I process it. Remember when we try to open a text file using Excel? There is a wizard which preview the content of the file, and guide us how to split the rows etc?
I have no issue with TStringList nor with TRichEdit.
The problem just occurs when I use TMemo. From the link you and RRUZ mentioned above, TRichEdit also has the similar limitation, but it holds 4096 in max.

Comment: That makes sense. One option would be to load it with a TStringList, then display the first n characters in a TMemo (assuming the user just needs to select the delimiter). Another possibility is again load via TStringList, but display the unparsed results in a grid. I don't know if that control has a limitation. You could use a TRichEdit, or search for a custom control that does not have that limitation. Years ago I had a 3rd-party Delphi control that acted like the Excel import wizard, but I don't recall the name.