# TMemo max width

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, text-editor, tmemo

Is there any way to make TMemo display text longer than 1024 into 1 line?
Take a look this simple code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    s: string;
    i: integer;
begin
    s := '';
    for i := 0 to 10000 do
      s := s + 'a';

    Memo1.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

The long text "s" will be displayed in multiple lines. The Memo1 will automatically wrap the text after 1024 characters.

Comment: This has [been discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365647/maximum-length-of-string-in-delphi-property-lines-of-tmemo), however there was no authoritative explanation as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7):

A TMemo is a wrapper for a native multi line edit control and is subject to the limitations it has. From [INFO: Size Limits for a Multiline Edit Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74225):

> A multiline edit control is also subject to the following limitations:
>
> - The maximum number of characters in a single line is 1024.
> - The maximum width of a line is 30,000 pixels.
> - The maximum number of lines is approximately 16,350.